# How to remove a word multiple times in Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am looking at a `pdf` document with about 300 pages and each one of those pages contains the word "test", which I'd like to remove.

So I am using `Tools` - `Protection` - `Search & remove text` in `Adobe Acrobat Pro`. Then I mark the results for redaction. When I `Apply Redactions` I get black bars above the words test.

What I actually want is removing the word without the text that is underneath it. There is text all over the page, whereas the word test fills almost the whole page.

I've tried to change the fill colour in the `Redaction Properties` to "no fill colour", but that just puts a white bar above the text.

So what I actually want is realy search and remove the word, instead of redacting.

Comment: Reader and Acrobat can't really edit PDF text. You can convert it to a Word file but you'll lose formatting. Your best bet would be InDesign.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the word "test" fills almost the entire page? Is it a watermark? Could it be cropped out of the each page?

Comment: I am able to edit pdf files in Acrobat Pro.
Yes it's a watermark but it's not added as such in the pdf. So I can't just use the acrobat function to remove a watermark. However cropping doesn't do the job of removing the watermark.

Comment: If you don't have InDesign, my only other suggestion would be to convert the text to a word processor, try to match the formatting the best you can, then convert that back to a PDF. If the word "test" is renderable and included with the converted/copied text, you can remove it via search and replace. Use the format parameters in the advanced search dialogue to differentiate any occurrences of the word "test" among the text you want to keep.

Comment: @PeterFitzgerald how do I remove the watermark in InDesign?